# java object creation

Tags: java, object, creation

```
public class ServersList {

    private Host host;
    private Server server;
    private InfoList infoList;
    private List<AbcInformation> abcInformation;

    @XmlElement(name = "Host")
    @JsonProperty("Host")
    public Host getHost() {
        return this.host;
    }

    //Get Set functions for all object
}
```

We have the above class. It contains some object of other classes and get/set methods as shown above. We are parsing an XML file and creating an array of ServersList class. For example,

```
ServersList[] serversArray = new ServersList[count];
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
  serversArray[index] = new ServersList();

  serversArray[index].setInfoList(serConfig
            .getInfoList());
  serversArray[index].setHost(serConfig
            .getHost());
  serversArray[index].setServer(serConfig
            .getServer());

  serversArray[index].getHost().setCid(
    listResponse.getHost().get(index).getCid());
  serversArray[index].getHost().setCName(
    listResponse.getHost().get(index).getCname());
  serversArray[index].getHost()
      .setCurrentName(listResponse.getHost().get(index)
     .getCurrentName());
  serversArray[index].getHost().setHostName(listResponse.getHost().
     get(index).getName());
  serversArray[index].getHost().setHostUuid(
     listResponse.getHost().get(index).getId());

}
```

Our problem is after the for loop all values of the serversArray array will be same (may be with last element in the xml). While debugging I understand that, every iteration the value of every rows are changed the values of current row. Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be serversArray[index] = new ServersList(); ?

Comment: as you are assigning the new object to every element, result will be the same.

Comment: you should also post the code where you are filling the `ServersList` object.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you're showing us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I have added copy constructors for the following classes

ServersList, Host, Server, InfoList, AbcInformation

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServersList sList=null;
        int count=10;
        ServersList[] serversArray = new ServersList[count];
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
          sList = new ServersList();
          sList.setHost(....);
          //..........other setter...........
          serversArray[index] = sList;
        }

        for (ServersList serversList : serversArray) {
            System.out.println(serversList.getHost());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added the following constructor in the ServersList class `public ServersList() {
  host = new Host();
  server = new Server();
  infoList = new InfoList();
 }` But no way..